# Wampserver is not working after installation of skype

Tags: wamp, wampserver, skype

Recently I installed skype and am aware of the skype port conflict error. I have removed 'use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections' from options and still no luck.

I have also uninstalled skype, reinstalled it and restarted my machine several times to no avail. Also, I just tried to run my torrent client and I am getting an error for the first time.

`http://localhost/` won't load now.

Comment: You are getting a 404 I'm assuming? have you tried http://127.0.0.1 ? If this works and you are on Windows try adding the following to your hosts file 127.0.0.1 localhost (Hosts file can be found in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same exact issue.  I tested port 80 by clicking on the wamp icon, going to Apache, and then service, and then test port 80.  It said that port 80 was currently being used by Microsoft-HTTPAIP/2.0.  After a bit of research, I found out that was was a process from Microsoft Reporting Services (result of installing SQL Server 2008).  I stopped the service from within the services console, and voila! It worked fine.

Comment: This is an incredibly useful tip! My problem was bloomin' Skype. I "quit" the application from its Tray Menu but only after finding this post did I realise that its process was still running (presumably crashed).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i did not have skype or any other app that might be using port 80.

I finally figured it was one of my Virtual Hosts causing issues, maybe try removing all your Vhosts or just un-comment: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache open the httpd.conf and change the lines

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen **8080**
```

Save the file and select “restart all services”, it is done.

Comment: Did not work for me and I made the changes to change Skype ports and even quit Skype. I wonder what else could be my problem? I have Windows 7 x64...